# Hierarchy structures

Tags: c#

I have a requirement to represent a hierarchical structure in a class within c#. 
The "leaf" nodes of the hierarchy need to be typed as either "Class A" or "Class B".

How do I achieve this.

Ok more detail

The classes involved are as follows

FieldClass - this has a bunch of properties

SegmentClass - a segment is a collection of fields

GroupClass - a group is a collection of segments or groups (ie there is a recursive relationship)

The nodes on the hierarchy can be either "segments" or "groups". So at the root level this a collection where the classes can be either of type segment or group.

Comment: Can you refine your question a bit, give an example or so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This represents your structure:

```
interface IGroupNode
{ }

class Group : IGroupNode
{
    List<IGroupNode> Children { get; set; }
}

class Segment : IGroupNode
{
    List<Field> Fields { get; set; }
}

class Field
{
    bool myProperty { get; set; }
}
```

And the tree can be instantiated with a list of IGroupNodes:

```
var rootLevel = new List<IGroupNode>();
```

Answer (score 4):

Make "ClassA" and "ClassB" implement a specific, shared interface (ie: `ILeafNode`).  You can then make your leaves `ILeafNode` and add either class type to the tree.

Comment: Yes either a common interface or a common base class (usually an abstract class as the base for Class A and Class B),  The leaf nodes can then be declared as being a type of the abstract base class

Answer (score 0):

As there is not a lot of information on what your exact requirement is, I will give you two starting places to work from.

One if you need to have a data structure of disparate child types, but that are still similar in typing look into using "[interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b%28VS.80%29.aspx)" or "[base classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5%28VS.71%29.aspx)" (in this case abstract classes). "Class A" and "Class B" can both derive from "ISomeClass" or "SomeClassBase" and would still be similar in structure. so that you can use a generic data structure such as List or Dictionary for them.

If you are wanting to visually display this list you can look into the [TreeView Control](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/scottlysle/treeviewbasics04152007195731pm/treeviewbasics.aspx) or its equivalent in the SilverLight or ASP.NET spaces.

Hope that helps and good luck.